# Replace values in powershell object

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

Using powershell to set the HA datastores for my VMware environment. I just don't know how to replace a certain value.

```
$Cluster = Get-Cluster $ClusterName | Get-View
$HAInfo = $Cluster.Configuration.DasConfig
```

Result of $HAinfo is this:

```
Enabled                    : True
VmMonitoring               : vmMonitoringDisabled
HostMonitoring             : enabled
VmComponentProtecting      : disabled
FailoverLevel              : 1
AdmissionControlPolicy     : VMware.Vim.ClusterFailoverResourcesAdmissionControlPolicy
AdmissionControlEnabled    : True
DefaultVmSettings          : VMware.Vim.ClusterDasVmSettings
Option                     : {das.ignoreRedundantNetWarning}
HeartbeatDatastore         : {Datastore-datastore-2367254, Datastore-datastore-1586741}
HBDatastoreCandidatePolicy : userSelectedDs
LinkedView                 :
```

Now I'm interested in the HeartbeatDatastore, which now contains:

```
Type      Value            
----      -----            
Datastore datastore-2367254
Datastore datastore-1586741
```

I need to replace the Value with new values. I could easily do this by just writing:

```
$Hainfo.HeartbeatDatastore[1].value = "newvalue"
```

But I can't be sure whether it contains 0, 1 or 2 values. My problem is that when for example it only contains 1 row (datastore, datastore-2367254), I don't know how I should add a new row with new values.

Not sure if this extra info is needed:

```
$Hainfo.HeartbeatDatastore | get-member


   TypeName: VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference

Name        MemberType Definition                    
----        ---------- ----------                    
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                
ToString    Method     string ToString()             
Type        Property   string Type {get;set;}        
Value       Property   string Value {get;set;}
```

Please assist.

Comment: Does that datastore that needs to be replaced always have the ID `datastore-1586741`?

Comment: Unfortunately, since `$hainfo.HeartbeatDatastore` is a collection of fixed size, you have to use the inefficient `+=` to add to the collection --> `$Hainfo.HeartbeatDatastore += 'Datastore-datastore-1586741`. Notice the prepending `Datastore-` because apparently that object type manipulates a set string and assumes the first chars up until the first `-` is the data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
$HAInfo.HeartbeatDatastore.Clear()
$dsObj1 = New-Object VMWare.Vim.ManagedObjectReference
$dsObj1 = here I fill it with the values I converted
$HAInfo.HeartbeatDatastore += $dsObj1

$dsObj2 = New-Object VMWare.Vim.ManagedObjectReference
$dsObj2 = here I fill it with the values I converted
$HAInfo.HeartbeatDatastore += $dsObj2
```